# Excel VBA range.characters properties not working

Tags: excel, vba, text

In my sheet "ATM", cell "C9" I have this simple formula:

="BANCONOTE DA " & TEXT(D5,"€ #.##0") & " MATERIALI:"

I'd like to make the font bold for TEXT(D5,"€ #.##0") and I guess my only option is thru VBA.

So I'm trying this in the ATM sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Worksheets("ATM").Range("C9")
    '.Characters(1, 1).Font.Bold = True 'all text becomes bold, weird!
    .Characters(14, 4).Font.Bold = True 'nothing at all!

    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Why is ".Characters(14, 4).Font.Bold = True" not working as expected?
Thank you.

Comment: It's clearly something to do with the fact that the cell contains a formula.  If you apply the same logic to a cell which contains a value of the resulting formula, it works.  Not sure of the solution but not actually sure you can do anything about it.

Comment: Following Skin's logic, the only way I can see to do this is to have C9 only contain text. You'd have to have another cell with the formula in - say B9, and then have an event set up, monitoring B9 for changes that updates C9 (with any formatting you need).

Answer (score 1):

The Characters collection cannot be controlled for a cell that contains a Formula.

You simply cannot format part of a string returned by a Formula

Comment: Thank you. I also tried copying the actual formula to another cell (i.e. K9) and put =K9 in cell C9 but doesn't work as well.

Comment: @Dolphin975 Why would you expect that to work?  `=K9` is still a formula that returns text.  It is not a text string.